# Dynamic LINQ to Entities where EntityType is generic

Tags: c#

First off, I'm a noob to EF and LINQ and even to a lesser degree, C# in general. Sorry if my question is poorly phrased or just boneheaded.

I have been searching all over for an example of this, but to no avail. I am trying to create a "search framework" that can accept any entity type in my model, and will present the user a UI to do custom searches with.

While there are 10's or maybe 100's of questions here and elsewhere relating to "Dynamic LINQ" or "Dynamic Query," it seems the one thing they all have in common is that the entity type is known at compile time. What if we DON'T know it at compile time? Meaning, the framework will just accept any entity type from the developer and then build the LINQ query up from there.

What I need to do is have that context.Customers be supplied at runtime, and then build up the "Where(s)" using something like PredicateBuilder, most likely PredicateBuilder.

so something like:

```
var query = from c in context.Customers select c;
```

would be more like:

```
var query = from c in AnyContext.AnyEntity select c;
```

I guess my question is what object can I use hold the arguments AnyContext and AnyEntity in my compiled code so that they can be replaced with a real context and entity at runtime?

I have looked thoroughly at PredicateBuilder and System.Linq.Dynamic examples but they all have the EntityType defined at design time. To me, that's not a dynamic query, just a dynamic predicate.

Comment: Is there a finite set of entity collections (tables) that can be searched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = from c in AnyContext.AnyEntity select c;
```

This is exactly the same as:

```
var query = AnyContext.AnyEntity;
```

In other words, if the context type and Entity Set property are selected by the user, you could just start with something like this:

```
var query = (IObjectSet<T>) GetObjectSetViaReflection(context, propertyName);
```

Also, I'm not sure what other versions of Entity Framework have this, but as of .NET 4.5, you can invoke CreateObjectSet to produce the query:

```
IObjectSet<T> query = context.CreateObjectSet<T>();
// or, if the context has multiple properties with the same type, 
// you can specify a name.
IObjectSet<T> query = context.CreateObjectSet<T>(propertyName);
```

Comment: @Babbleon: No, I used `<T>` because that's the standard name for a generic class, and your question title indicated that the entity type is generic. `GetObjectSetViaReflection` is pseudo-code. There are plenty of tutorials on getting the property off of an object, so I figured that was outside the scope of this question.

Comment: In EF, the `DbContext` has a way to get a generic set, like: `Context.Set<TEntity>()`.